# Showing that the normalized power method converges to eigenvector

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to show that if $ \lambda_1 >0 \Rightarrow $ the vectors $ x^{(k)} $ converges to an eigenvector. 
Where k is the number of iteration, and k $ \rightarrow \infty $
I started by writing $ x^{(k)}$ 
$$ x^{(k)}= \frac{A x^{(k-1)} }{ ||A x^{(k-1)}||} $$
$$ x^{(k)}= \frac{A^{k-1} x^{(0)} }{ ||A^{k-1} x^{(0)}||} $$

In the assigment i was told, that i could use
1. there is a single eigenvalue of max modulus
2. there is a linearly independent set of n eigenvalues

I just can't see that this can help me. I tried to write out the coordinates, but that didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fact (2), write your initial seed vector $x^{(0)}$ as a linear combination of all the eigenvectors, say:
$$x^{(0)} = a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \cdots + a_n x_n,$$
where (by fact (1)) $x_1$ is the eigenvector with largest eigenvalue . Then,
$$A^k x^{(0)} = a_1 \lambda_1^k x_1 + a_2 \lambda_2^k x_2 + \cdots + a_n \lambda_n^k x_n.$$
When you normalize, I think you should find that the denominator grows like $\lambda_1^k$ so that, in the limit, you're left with $x_1$.